# FIND and REPLACE wp_posts AND IGNORE custom post type mysql query

Tags: posts, mysql

does exists some MYSQL query for FIND and REPLACE wp_posts AND IGNORE all other wordpress and buddypress posts (buddypress-docs) and also custom post type = portfolio ? I want to find and replace only wordpress blog content and I don't want to touch other posts. 
I use following MYSQL query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,'Item to replace here','Replacement text here');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `WHERE` clause to your query for `post_type = 'post'`.

Comment: `UPDATE wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'portfolio' SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,'Item to replace here','Replacement text here');`  Do you mean like this? Does it ignore post_type Portfolio?

Comment: that's not valid SQL, WHERE clause goes last. See the MySQL manual for how to correctly format a query. `post_type = 'portfolio'` will affect only portfolio type, I meant exactly as I typed it- `post_type = 'post'`. Look at the table itself and it will be obvious.

Comment: I have only one custom post type portfolio, I am not an MySQL expert, it is a strange answer to go and look at MySQL manual how to correctly format a query, I thought that for this purpose serves this site, to do not go to any site to study MySQL language.

Comment: `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE WHERE post_type = 'post' (post_content,'Item to replace here','Replacement text here');`  Sorry, I understand now, the WHERE tells what exactly will be replaced and not what will be ignored, I am new here so I can't confirm that your answer is correct

Comment: I answered as a courtesy, MySQL questions are off-topic here.